# One sample test for helpfulness ratings

Tags: categorical-data, t-test, sample, rating

I have some questionnaire data were participants rated with [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] whether a product helped with respect to several attributes. 0 indicates that it didn't help at all and 4 is very much.

I am wondering whether I can somehow get some significance for each of the different attributes whether the product really helped.

My initial thought was to use a one-sample t-test with h0 = 0 (did not help at all). However, I am not sure whether setting h0 that way is acceptable and also if this test works with this data from a non-continuous scale.

Comment: That fact that you don't know what hypothesis to formulate suggests you don't need a test.  Why not just summarize the data?

Comment: @whuber Sure, I can do that. I was just thinking whether there is more to gain.

Answer (score 0):

I would just table the means of the help ratings for each attribute, and then order them down the page from "most helpful" down to "least helpful". You could also calculate the variances, though I'm not sure this would be helpful.